# Custom ChargeTransactionPayment type for extrinsics

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, api, custom-types, typescript

if the type for extrinsic verification `pub struct ChargeTransactionPayment<T: Config>` has been changed on a chain, how do we update the polkadot.js API to use the new types? Suppose the type has been changed to

```
pub struct ChargeTransactionPayment<T: Config> {
    pub scheme: u8,
    pub asset_id: Option<ChargeAssetIdOf<T>>,
    pub tip: BalanceOf<T>,
}
```

How can I let the polkdot.js api know about this update and set them before executing an extrinsic? I tried adding it to the registry and calling the extrinsic as shown below. but it give me the error `"createType(ChargeAssetTxPayment):: DoNotConstruct: Cannot construct unknown type ChargeAssetTxPayment"`

```
api.registry.createType("ChargeAssetTxPayment", {
                    extrinsic: {
                        scheme:'2',
                        asset_id: 4,
                        tip: 10
                    },
                    payload: {}
                })
```

I am trying to do something similar to what statemint did, is it possible to set these custom parameters using the api directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible to inject types into polkadot-js api. When instantiating an `ApiPromise`, you may also pass in one of the following:

```
{
    types,
    typesAlias
    typesBundle,
    typesChain,
    typesSpec
}
```

Here is a [quick example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/src/main.ts#L46-L62) of the parameters being passed in.

These Types are present [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/types/src/types/registry.ts#L80-L106) for more information. It's good to search through each type the fields are set to, in order to understand which field best fits your situation.

I created a tool a while back to help users understand and how to generate a typesBundle specifically using polkadot-js/apps-config for specific chains. This tool can be found here: https://github.com/paritytech/generate-type-bundle

Additionally, if there has been a type updated in substrate or polkadot and it hasn't been properly mirrored in polkadot-js, the best approach is to file an [issue](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/issues).